# Subset of R^3 with a basis consisting of only two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Here is Z a subset of $R^3$

$$ Z =  [(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1 + x_2 = 0] $$

In class, we were told that (1, -1, 0) and (1, -1, 1) is a basis of Z.
I know that a basis is family of vectors with two characteristics :

1. The vectors have to be linearly independent (the following are)
2. They have to span the vector space

I was expecting to have 3 vectors and there are only two in the basis. My intuition is that it comes from the fact that we have a condition only on : $$ x_1 + x_2 = 0 $$

Is it correct ?
Would it be the same with a similar subset with a condition like this one ? : $$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 $$

Comment: I think $Z=\{(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x_{1}+x_{2}=0,x_{3}\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way of thinking about it:

- You start in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has three dimensions.
- You add *one* linear constraint. This leaves a space of $3-1=2$ dimensions.
- Any two non-colinear vectors in a two-dimensional space form a basis.

Adding the constraint $x_1+x_2=0$ (and, in general, any one linear constraint) reduces the dimension of your space. You can pick any value of $x_1$, and any value of $x_3$, but then the value of $x_2$ is already determined for you. This leaves only two degrees of freedom, so your space is two dimensional.

Another way of thinking about it is that $x_1+x_2=0$ is the equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and a plane is two-dimensional.

Comment: Great answer, and precisely what I was going to say. +1

Comment: Thank you a lot for this